# Mat-Option Showing Options but Not Selecting When Clicked

Tags: angular, angular-material

New developer here. Working with Angular 7 and using mat-option to list names added to a database. The names appear fine when the field is clicked, however when you try to select the name nothing happens.

From the HTML:

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="leaderratingForm">
    <div>
        <div>
            <mat-form-field>
                <mat-select placeholder="Select a Leader" formControlName="LeaderId" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let leaderId of leaders" [value]="leaderId.LeaderId">{{leaderId.LeaderName}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

From the controller:

```
export class LeaderratingCreateComponent implements OnInit {

  leaderratingForm: FormGroup;
  leaders: Leader[];

  constructor(private _leaderratingService: LeaderratingService, private _form: FormBuilder, private _router: Router, private leaderService: LeaderService) { 
    this.createForm();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.leaderService.getLeaders().subscribe((leaders: Leader[]) => {this.leaders = leaders; });
  }

  createForm() {
    this.leaderratingForm = this._form.group({
    LeaderID: new FormControl,
    SpeakingAbilityRating: new FormControl,
    EngagingRating: new FormControl,
    AuthenticRating: new FormControl,
    RapportRating: new FormControl,
    });
  }
```

This is identical code to what I'm using elsewhere for a component that actually works as expected (drop down options are there and can be selected). Thanks!

Comment: try `                <mat-select placeholder="Select a Leader" formControlName="LeaderId" required>
                    <mat-option *ngFor="let leaderId of leaders" [value]="leaderId?.LeaderId">{{leaderId?.LeaderName}}
                    </mat-option>
                </mat-select>`

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, the Template and component have some inconsistencies with the `Leader` property names.

You have `LeaderID` in your component but `LeaderId` in your Template. This should give an error because you typed `formControlName="LeaderId"` in your `<mat-select>` (as opposed to `LeaderID`) .

You'll get something like:

> Cannot find control with name: 'LeaderId'

If you still have issues selecting the element after changing that, check if your `Leader` class/interface is consistent as well: you might be trying to access `[value]="leaderId.LeaderId"` when your `Leader` class/interface has a `LeaderID` property instead

Hope that helps :)